Python redis client timeout does not work
If redis connection is fine and a request is running for a long time, timeout works correctly.
But if redis server unavailable, timeout does not work.
This code raises exception after 5 seconds, instead 0.007
from redis import Redis

r = Redis('redis', 6379, 7, socket_timeout=.007, socket_connect_timeout=.007)
results = r.mget('key1', 'key2', 'key3')

Compose
version: "3.8"

services:
  api:
    build:
      context: .
    command: ["uvicorn", "run_api:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80", "--reload"]
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./:/app/
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    environment:
      ...

# Disabled for test timeout
#  redis:
#    image: redis:5.0.3-alpine
#

How to fix it?
Python redis client is 5.2.0, python 3.12.

0.007 sounds like a very small value. What happens if you set the value of the timeout parameters to 1? Does it timeout after 1 second or still after 5 seconds?

Still 5 seconds. 1 decond is very very mutch in my case, no more than 15 ms.
